# Determine dependencies beetween colums in table

Tags: sql, database-normalization

I have a table in a denormalized form like below:

```
Col1               Col2      Col3            Col4 Col5 
Paris              France    Europe          1     4
Paris              France    Europe          2     5
Paris              France    Europe          3     6
Washington D.C.    USA       North America   8     9
Washington D.C.    USA       North America   7     7
... 
many more rows
...
```

In order to normalize it I need to understand the structure of data.

Presumably there is a logical dependency from Col3 to Col2 and from Col2 to Col1. Paris isthe capital of France and France is a country in europe.

How can I prove this with a SQL query? Basically I need to prove that there are combinations like "Paris - France - Europe", "Washington D.C. - USA - North America" and so on, but never "Paris - USA - Europe" or "Washington D.C. - USA - Europe" for example. Actually the query should also prove right if I find something like "Berlin - Germany - Africa" in my DB, as long as I do not find "Berlin - Germany - Europe".

Comment: Can you update your question to use real data?  Five columns containing numbers and letters is a bit abstract.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select col3, count(*), count(distinct col2)
from t
group by col3;
```

The expectation is that the second column would have a value of "1".  You could get all examples with multiple values in `col2` by using `having count(distinct col2) > 1`.

Of course, cities do have the same name.  Paris, for instance, is a rather well-known [city in Texas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paris,_Texas).

Comment: Thanks, looks like there is a semicolon in your answer too much though.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

SQL queries can *disprove* a dependency, since you only need a single counter example.  But proving a dependency means showing it can *never* be broken, while the current DB contents only represent a single example.